# Priority in multiple css files in a web page

Tags: html, css

I Have used multiple css files to make my code clear. This cause some priority issue in styling because some codes over write the other.

So i was wondering if there is any way i could priortize the css files so that high priority files are not over written.

Comment: Hello, use !important after the properties values in your files. For Example  `#idName{display: none!important}` here this will consider this more important than any other property..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While linking the css files, move the high priority file the end.
The last included file will have the highest priority as long as you dont have an inline style